# FTP connection via Load Balancer cd works ls fails

Tags: ftp, load-balancing, haproxy

Below is the configuration.

```
Client is a linux server IP: 10.204.21.143. This server is only reachable to HA Proxy server.

HA Proxy Server IP: 10.204.24.71 (Its a Solaris 11.3 Server) 

Back end Server where the FTP Server is running : 10.212.22.31 This server is only reachable to HA Proxy Server only and not to Client Server.
```

HA Proxy Configuration:

```
$ cat haproxy.cfg
global
      maxconn 15000
      pidfile dmshaproxy.pid
      daemon
      stats socket dmshaproxy.sock mode 0600 level admin
      spread-checks 5

defaults
      mode tcp
      retries 3
      maxconn 15000
      contimeout 5s
      clitimeout 300s
      srvtimeout 300s
      option contstats

listen FTP 10.204.24.71:2121
    server ftp-serv00 10.212.22.31:21 check inter 20s
$
```

Now I am able to connect from the client, execute the cd command and it works. but ls does not work.

```
[root@qa-lt143 ~]# ftp 10.204.24.71 2121
Connected to 10.204.24.71 (10.204.24.71).
220 ::ffff:10.212.22.31 FTP server ready
Name (10.204.24.71:root): oracle
331 Password required for oracle
Password:
230 User oracle logged in
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> cd RMAN_BKP
250 CWD command successful
ftp> pwd
257 "/export/home/oracle/RMAN_BKP" is the current directory
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,212,22,31,137,99).    <--- This IP is of backend server. but it should be of HA-Proxy Server. Not sure why its taking the backend server.
ftp: connect: Connection timed out
ftp>
```

I see that when I do ls it take the Back-end ip to connect which is not reachable from client server. Not sure why it is not taking the HA-Proxy server IP.

Also I tried the same with the Active connection then also it did not work. This time it took its local server IP.

```
[root@qa-lt143 ~]# ftp -A 10.204.24.71 2121
Connected to 10.204.24.71 (10.204.24.71).
220 ::ffff:10.212.22.31 FTP server ready
Name (10.204.24.71:root): oracle
331 Password required for oracle
Password:
230 User oracle logged in
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> cd RMAN_BKP
250 CWD command successful
ftp> pwd
257 "/export/home/oracle/RMAN_BKP" is the current directory
ftp> ls
500 Illegal PORT command
ftp: bind: Address already in use
ftp> debug
Debugging on (debug=1).
ftp> ls
---> PORT 10,204,21,143,180,120
500 Illegal PORT command
ftp>
```

Please Help.

Comment: Proxying FTP is a messy proposition, because of the awkward internal workings of the protocol.  You will have to use passive mode, **and** you'll need a `listen` section to handle the entire range of ephemeral ports the FTP server will use, **and** you'll need to configure your FTP server daemon so that it knows to negotiate connections using the proxy's external address.  If there's any way you can use STFP instead, you should consider doing that.  It's very straightforward, not to mention the security aspects.

Comment: If you absolutely _must_ do load-balancing of FTP connections, you might find ProFTPD's [`mod_proxy`](https://github.com/Castaglia/proftpd-mod_proxy) useful.  _(Full disclaimer: I'm the author of it.)_